# Minecraft goes black on 12.04 and EEE901

Tags: minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't get Minecraft to run on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171991/cant-get-minecraft-to-run-on-ubuntu)

Since downgrading to an older release of Ubuntu won't solve the problem for this version, I try to fix it this way. It is basically this guy's problem but with a little difference: [Minecraft goes black on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129241/minecraft-goes-black-on-12-04)

Upgrading LWJGL does not work, as they are "already updated" in Minecraft 1.3. I think that other users of EEE901 have the same problem. I will still downgrade to other versions because it might be reasonable to try the Java JRE 6 trick. I will keep track on this thread on another computer meanwhile.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/sadmin/.minecraft/bin/natives/liblwjgl.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1924)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:69)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:65)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:81)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:98)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.F(SourceFile:1857)
    at aof.<init>(SourceFile:20)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(SourceFile:77)
    at anw.<init>(SourceFile:36)
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftApplet.init(SourceFile:36)
    at net.minecraft.Launcher.replace(Launcher.java:136)
    at net.minecraft.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:79)
```

Answer (score 5):

Download the latest copy of LWJGL from here http://lwjgl.org/download.php and extract it

Copy the following to ~/.minecraft/bin

- jinput.jar
- lwjgl.jar
- lwjgl_util.jar

And the following to ~/.minecraft/bin/natives

- libjinput-linux.so
- libjinput-linux64.so
- liblwjgl.so
- liblwjgl64.so
- libopenal.so
- libopenal64.so

Then restart Minecraft

Make sure you overwrite the files that Minecraft downloads, they are out of date.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.